# Can't build app after upgrading Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

After upgrading Android Studio to 1.2, I can't run my app, it prompts for errors like this, ( I have Google Play Services in my build.gradle) :

```
    D:\MYAPP\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\7.0.0\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
:hengaamLibrary:mergeDebugTestResources FAILED
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was both Android Studio 1.2 beta, which seems to have problems with Android Wear and also long path name ( more than 256 characters).

The long path name is only on Windows, no such problem on Linux & Mac.

Comment: Yup. 1.2 beta 1/2/3 are pretty buggy and I've had the similar problem so I have no choice but to downgrade to 1.1.